# Why sum of squared errors for logistic regression not used and instead maximum likelihood estimation is used to fit the model?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, least-squares, linear

I have a doubt on why sum of squared errors is not used for Logistic regression and instead maximum likelihood estimation is used and also why not the vice versa.

**Edited**

Many were asking me to clarify the question, my intention was to know about using a squared error loss function to find β vs MLE

Comment: Your observations are of the form $0$ and $1$.  If you tried to apply the function $f(x)=\log\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)$ to these, you might have difficulties

Comment: Sir, can you be more specific about the difficulties

Comment: If you insist: neither $\log\left(\frac{0}{1}\right)$ nor $\log\left(\frac{1}{0}\right)$ are finite, which makes makes linear regression of the transformed probabilities difficult.  You could instead try non-linear regression, but then you lose the arithmetic advantages of linear regression and you should consider carefully your loss function: using maximum likelihood rewards accurate prediction of high and low probability events

Comment: Minimizing squared errors is a maximum likelihood estimation -- of the wrong likelihood function.

Comment: @Henry: I don't support this idea, but you *could* keep the response unchanged (i.e. $y = 0, 1$) and have the predictions be $\hat y = \frac{e^\eta}{1 + e^\eta}$ with $\eta = X^T \beta$, and finally minimize $\sum (y_i - \hat y_i)^2$. I *believe* this is what the OP intended in the question.

Comment: @CliffAB my understanding of the OPs question is the same as yours. Can you explain (or refer me to) why fisher scoring/IWLS for MLE would be slower than some numerical approximation for the above loss function? I'm legitimately interested because I thought fisher scoring was a real game changer for GLMs.

Comment: @ilanman: Fisher scoring is the algorithm of choice in most cases, but I'm not sure I'd say it's a game changer? In fact, in the case of a canonical link function, Fisher's scoring is [*identical*](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~mlevins/Lecnotes/Lecture_fitting.pdf) to Newton Raphson. In the case when the non-canonical link function is used, my understanding is that it has guarantees that make it a more stable algorithm. But for many vanilla regression problems, NR itself is adequately stable, so the advantage is minimal!

Comment: Right. Game changer is a bit strong :) just trying to think why FS alg would not be beneficial in the case of the OPs question re MLE vs squared loss, per your comment below.

Comment: It would be very helpful if the OP edited the question to clarify which, if any, of the comments and answers is hitting the target.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Do the answers below help?

Comment: @ilanman yes, your answer really helped me, thank you!

Comment: Great. Feel free to accept it by clicking the check :)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I don't know how duplicate works but isn't this question older than the one you referred.

Comment: @Sri Harsha Pinninti: It doesn't matter which post is older, what matters is that the refefenced post answers your question.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen okay, I will check the question you referenced but the answer provided by ilanman answered my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, least squares (or sum of squared errors) is a possible loss function to use to fit your coefficients. There's nothing technically wrong about it.

However there are number of reasons why MLE is a more attractive option. In addition to those in the comments, here are two more:

**Computational efficiency**

Because the likelihood function of a logistic regression model is a member of the [exponential family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family), we can use [Fisher's Scoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_algorithm) algorithm to efficiently solve for $\beta$. In my experience, this algorithm converges in only a few steps. To solve least squares numerically will likely take longer.

Lest this gets lost, per @vbox's comment:

> learning parameters for any machine learning model (such as logistic regression) is much easier if the cost function is convex. And, it's not too difficult to show that, for logistic regression, the cost function for the sum of squared errors is not convex, while the cost function for the log-likelihood is.

**MLE has very nice properties**

Solutions using MLE have nice properties such:

- consistency: meaning that with more data, our estimate of $\beta$ gets closer to the true value.
- asymptotic normality: meaning that with more data, our estimate of $\beta$ is approximately normal distributed with variance that decreases with $O(\frac{1}{n})$
- functional invariance: nice property to have when dealing with multiple parameters (nuisance parameters) and calculating the [profile likelihood](https://www.stat.tamu.edu/~suhasini/teaching613/profile_likelihood.pdf).

Among [others](http://people.stern.nyu.edu/wgreene/Lugano2013/Greene-Chapter-14.pdf).

**However using Least Squares does have some benefits**

Least squares tends to be more robust to outliers because an outlier can be wrong by at most 1 (because $(1-0)^2 = 1$), whereas under a negative log likelihood loss function, the distance can be arbitrarily large.

For more information check [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24904/least-squares-logistic-regression) or [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29325/what-is-the-difference-between-linear-regression-and-logistic-regression) out.

**Edited**

My interpretation of the OPs question is why do we use MLE instead of a square loss function to determine $\beta$ in a logistic regression model of the form:

$$logit(P(Y=1|X)) = x\beta$$

Where $P(Y=1|X) = f(x;\beta) = \frac{e^{x\beta}}{1 + e^{x\beta}} = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-x\beta}}$

So the loss function looks like:

$$\sum_{i} (y_i - f(x_i;\beta))^2 = \sum_{i} (y_i - \frac{1}{1 + e^{-x\beta}})^2$$

where $y_i$'s take values 0/1.

When I talk about computational efficiency, I mean finding the $\beta$ which minimizes the above vs. Fisher Scoring on the likelihood function.

Comment: OLS is generally *more* computationally efficient than logistic regression; a single step of Fisher's scoring should have more computational costs than solving the entire OLS solution.

Comment: Is this true for least squares with a logistic function? Can you point me to a reference?

Comment: Ah, so you mean something like a GLM with a logistic link and Gaussian pdf. In that case, it would not be in closed form like OLS, but I am extremely doubtful it will be faster.

Comment: Not Gaussian PDF. Just a squared loss function with logic link. Right, not closed form. I'm pretty sure fisher scoring is faster than standard numerical methods. Unless you could show me otherwise. I'll include detail in my answer to be clear.

Comment: Maximizing likelihood based on Gaussian PDF = minimizing squared error loss function.

Comment: I added some clarification above. Nowhere do I make the Gaussian assumption, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: To add to ilanman's answer, learning parameters for any machine learning model (such as logistic regression) is much easier if the cost function is [convex](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219899/why-do-we-want-an-objective-function-to-be-a-convex-function). And, it's not too difficult to show that, for logistic regression, the cost function for the sum of squared errors is not convex, while the cost function for the log-likelihood is.

Comment: @vbox: ah, I forget about the non-convexity issue. In that case, I could see how using the logistic transform with a squared error loss could be slower. Sorry for the distraction.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm not getting the point of ilanman's answer as well as of some of the comments here, but afaiks, the answer is simply that

OLS = log L(Gaussian)

i.e. the OLS corresponds to the log likelihood of a regression with a normal / Gaussian distribution. You can see this by logging the formula for the Gaussian - the $\sigma$ will factor out, and you see that the OLS maximizes the likelihood.

So, OLS estimation IS MLE for a Gaussian error.

Logistic Regression assumes a Bernoulli / Binomial error, that is why you don't do OLS.

Comment: I *think* the OP is asking about using a squared error loss function to find $\beta$ vs MLE.

Comment: Hmm ... maybe it would be useful if the OP could clarify what the question was. In my world, the main use of logistic regression is 0/1 data, and there you would like to fit a glm with logit link / binomial distribution - OLS simply doesn't fit to that assumptions.

Comment: I agree, but technically you could fit a squared loss function. And to be fair, no where does the OP use the term OLS.